# How to control the height and width of rectangular box in latex table?

Tags: tables

[image]Using the following code, I could successfully draw blue box inside the table, but cannot control height and in particular the width of the box. In other words, I cannot make the box fit to the width of my table. Any tip on how to easily control the width and the height of the box, please?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawBox}[3][]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \draw[black,#1]
      ($(#2)+(-0.25em,2.0ex)$) rectangle
      ($(#3)+(-0.25em,-0.375ex)$);}
}
\begin{table}[H] 
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c c c c c}
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-11} 
\\[-1.8ex] & $\sigma^l$ & $\sigma^\pi$ & $\sigma^k$ & ROE & log(der) & log($\phi_l$) & log($\phi_k$)& TFP& HHI &$\mu$ \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) &(7) & (8) & (9) & (10)\\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textbf{Top} & $-$0.087 & $-$0.279 & 0.087 & $-$0.018 & 0.111 & $-$0.090 & $-$1.372$^{*}$ & $-$7.257 & $-$0.006 & 3.279$^{*}$ \\ 
$\times$\textbf{Post}  & (0.083) & (0.204) & (0.083) & (0.016) & (0.240) & (0.217) & (0.756) & (4.679) & (0.046) & (1.823) \\ 
\tikzmark{top left 2}\color{red}{Top30}& $-$0.127$^{***}$ & 0.115$^{***}$ & 0.127$^{***}$ & 0.004 & 0.102$^{*}$ & 0.102$^{**}$ & 0.162 & 1.101 & $-$0.031$^{***}$ & 1.214$^{***}$ \\ 
  \color{red}{PostRe} & (0.018) & (0.044) & (0.018) & (0.004) & (0.055) & (0.049) & (0.152) & (1.070) & (0.011) & (0.424) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & & &\\ 
 Top3 & $-$0.100$^{*}$ & 0.184 & 0.100$^{*}$ & 0.034$^{***}$ & 0.077 & 0.282$^{*}$ & 1.456$^{***}$ & $-$1.161 & 0.143$^{***}$  & \tikzmark{bottom right 2}3.548$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.061) & (0.149) & (0.061) & (0.012) & (0.176) & (0.159) & (0.554) & (3.427) & (0.033) & (1.335) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & & & \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{10}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular}} 
\DrawBox[ultra thick, blue]{top left 2}{bottom right 2}
\scriptsize \textit{Note:} 
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code snippet [minimally compilable](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: thanks, I just did so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever else you end up doing, please don't use the `\resizebox` sledgehammer to force a tabular-like environment into the width of text block.

I suggest you employ a `tabular*` environment, with width set to `\textwidth`. With normal-sized margins, this approach will only require you to issue a `\small` directive, for a 10% reduction in the nominal font size. I further suggest that you align the numbers in the ten data columns on their decimal markers. This may be done with, say, the help of the `dcolumn` package.

I've left the `\tikzmark{bottom right 2}` directive where it was in your code, i.e., at the end of next-to-last column. If you want the blue rectangle to include the final column as well, just shift `\tikzmark{bottom right 2}` to the final cell of the row in question.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand{\DrawBox}[3][]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \draw[black,#1]
      ($(#2)+(-0.25em,2.0ex)$) rectangle
      ($(#3)+(-0.25em,-0.375ex)$);}
}

%% new code:
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{$}c<{$}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h] 
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out intercolumn whitespace
\small % 10% linear reduction in font size

\caption{The table's caption\strut}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
     l 
     *{10}{d{2.5}} % align numbers on decimal markers
     }
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Dependent variables} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-11} 
& \mc{\sigma^l} & \mc{\sigma^\pi} & \mc{\sigma^k} 
& \mc{\text{ROE}} & \mc{\log(\mathrm{der})} & \mc{\log(\phi_l)} 
& \mc{\log(\phi_k)} & \mc{\text{TFP}} & \mc{\text{HHI}} & \mc{\mu} \\ 
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} & \mc{(5)} 
& \mc{(6)} & \mc{(7)} & \mc{(8)} & \mc{(9)} & \mc{(10)} \\ 
\midrule
\textbf{Top} 
& -0.087 & -0.279 & 0.087 & -0.018 & 0.111 
& -0.090 & -1.372^{*} & -7.257 & -0.006 & 3.279^{*} \\ 
$\times$\textbf{Post}  
& (0.083) & (0.204) & (0.083) & (0.016) & (0.240) 
& (0.217) & (0.756) & (4.679) & (0.046) & (1.823) \\ 
\addlinespace
\tikzmark{top left 2}
\color{red}{Top30}
& -0.127^{***} & 0.115^{***} & 0.127^{***} & 0.004 & 0.102^{*} 
& 0.102^{**} & 0.162 & 1.101 & -0.031^{***} & 1.214^{***} \\ 
\color{red}{PostRe} 
& (0.018) & (0.044) & (0.018) & (0.004) & (0.055) 
& (0.049) & (0.152) & (1.070) & (0.011) & (0.424) \\ 
\addlinespace
Top3 
& -0.100^{*} & 0.184 & 0.100^{*} 
& 0.034^{***} & 0.077 & 0.282^{*} 
& 1.456^{***} & -1.161 & 0.143^{***}
\ \ \tikzmark{bottom right 2} & 3.548^{***} \\ 
& (0.061) & (0.149) & (0.061) & (0.012) & (0.176) 
& (0.159) & (0.554) & (3.427) & (0.033) & (1.335) \\ 
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{11}{@{}l}{\footnotesize $^{*}\ p<0.1$; $^{**}\ p<0.05$; $^{***}\ p<0.01$} \\ 
\end{tabular*}
\DrawBox[ultra thick, blue]{top left 2}{bottom right 2}

\smallskip
\footnotesize\textit{Note}: \dots

\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

No need to use TikZ, here you find a solution with `tabularray` and `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath} 
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\NewColumnType{A}[1][-1.3*]{Q[si={input-symbols = {()},
    group-digits  = false,
    table-format=#1,
    table-number-alignment=center,
    explicit-sign,},c]}

\begin{document}
If you would like to include the last column:   
    
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={l*{4}{A}*{2}{A[1.3]}AA[-1.3]AA[-1.3**]},
    row{1-3}={guard},
    row{even[4]}={belowsep+=-1ex},
    columns={font=\scriptsize},
    column{1}={leftsep=1pt,rightsep=0pt},
    cell{1}{2}={c=10}{c, font=\itshape\scriptsize},
    cell{Y}{1}={c=11}{r, mode=math},
    cell{2-Y}{2-Z}={mode=math},
    cell{4-5}{1}={font=\bfseries\scriptsize},
    cell{6-7}{1}={fg=red},
    hline{1} = {1}{-}{solid},
    hline{1} = {2}{-}{solid},
    hline{2} = {2-Z}{solid,leftpos=-1,endpos},
    hline{4} = {solid},
    hline{6} = {blue, wd=2pt},
    vline{1,Z} = {6-X}{blue,wd=2pt},
    hline{X} = {1}{-}{blue,wd=2pt},
    hline{X} = {2}{-}{solid},
    hline{X} = {3}{-}{solid},
    }
    & Dependent variable: &&&&&&&&&\\ 
    & \sigma^l & \sigma^\pi & \sigma^k & \textrm{ROE} & \log(\textrm{der}) & \log(\phi_l) & \log(\phi_k)& \textrm{TFP}& \textrm{HHI} &\mu \\ 
    & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) &(7) & (8) & (9) & (10)\\ 
    Top & -0.087 & -0.279 & 0.087 & -0.018 & 0.111 & -0.090 & -1.372* & -7.257 & -0.006 & 3.279* \\
    $\times$Post & (0.083) & (0.204) & (0.083) & (0.016) & (0.240) & (0.217) & (0.756) & (4.679) & (0.046) & (1.823) \\ 
    Top30 & -0.127*** & 0.115*** & 0.127*** & 0.004 & 0.102* & 0.102** & 0.162 & 1.101 & -0.031*** & 1.214*** \\
    PostRe & (0.018) & (0.044) & (0.018) & (0.004) & (0.055) & (0.049) & (0.152) & (1.070) & (0.011) & (0.424) \\ 
    Top3 & -0.100* & 0.184 & 0.100* & 0.034*** & 0.077 & 0.282* & 1.456*** & -1.161 & 0.143***  & 3.548*** \\ 
    & (0.061) & (0.149) & (0.061) & (0.012) & (0.176) & (0.159) & (0.554) & (3.427) & (0.033) & (1.335) \\
    ^{*}\textrm{p}<0.1; ^{**}\textrm{p}<0.05; ^{***}\textrm{p}<0.01 &&&&&&&&&&\\ 
    Note:&&&&&&&&&&\\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{table} 
If you would \emph{not} like to include the last column:    
    
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={l*{4}{A}*{2}{A[1.3]}AA[-1.3]A[-1.3**]A[1.3**]},
    row{1-3}={guard},
    row{even[4]}={belowsep+=-1ex},
    columns={font=\scriptsize},
    column{1}={leftsep=1pt,rightsep=0pt},
    cell{1}{2}={c=10}{c, font=\itshape\scriptsize},
    cell{Y}{1}={c=11}{r, mode=math},
    cell{2-Y}{2-Z}={mode=math},
    cell{4-5}{1}={font=\bfseries\scriptsize},
    cell{6-7}{1}={fg=red},
    hline{1} = {1}{-}{solid},
    hline{1} = {2}{-}{solid},
    hline{2} = {2-Z}{solid,leftpos=-1,endpos},
    hline{4} = {solid},
    hline{6} = {1-Y}{blue, wd=2pt},
    vline{1,Y} = {6-X}{blue,wd=2pt},
    hline{X} = {1}{1-Y}{blue,wd=2pt},
    hline{X} = {2}{-}{solid},
    hline{X} = {3}{-}{solid},
    }
    & Dependent variable: &&&&&&&&&\\ 
    & \sigma^l & \sigma^\pi & \sigma^k & \textrm{ROE} & \log(\textrm{der}) & \log(\phi_l) & \log(\phi_k)& \textrm{TFP}& \textrm{HHI} &\mu \\ 
    & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) &(7) & (8) & (9) & (10)\\ 
    Top & -0.087 & -0.279 & 0.087 & -0.018 & 0.111 & -0.090 & -1.372* & -7.257 & -0.006 & 3.279* \\
    $\times$Post & (0.083) & (0.204) & (0.083) & (0.016) & (0.240) & (0.217) & (0.756) & (4.679) & (0.046) & (1.823) \\ 
    Top30 & -0.127*** & 0.115*** & 0.127*** & 0.004 & 0.102* & 0.102** & 0.162 & 1.101 & -0.031*** & 1.214*** \\
    PostRe & (0.018) & (0.044) & (0.018) & (0.004) & (0.055) & (0.049) & (0.152) & (1.070) & (0.011) & (0.424) \\ 
    Top3 & -0.100* & 0.184 & 0.100* & 0.034*** & 0.077 & 0.282* & 1.456*** & -1.161 & 0.143***  & 3.548*** \\ 
    & (0.061) & (0.149) & (0.061) & (0.012) & (0.176) & (0.159) & (0.554) & (3.427) & (0.033) & (1.335) \\
    ^{*}\textrm{p}<0.1; ^{**}\textrm{p}<0.05; ^{***}\textrm{p}<0.01 &&&&&&&&&&\\ 
    Note:&&&&&&&&&&\\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a command `\Block` to draw a frame around a rectangle of cells.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{$}c<{$}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h] 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} 
\small 

\caption{The table's caption}

\begin{NiceTabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
     l 
     *{10}{S[input-symbols = {()}]} 
     }[notes/para]
\toprule
 & \Block{1-9}{Dependent variables} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-11} 
& \mc{\sigma^l} & \mc{\sigma^\pi} & \mc{\sigma^k} 
& \mc{\text{ROE}} & \mc{\log(\mathrm{der})} & \mc{\log(\phi_l)} 
& \mc{\log(\phi_k)} & \mc{\text{TFP}} & \mc{\text{HHI}} & \mc{\mu} \\ 
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} & \mc{(5)} 
& \mc{(6)} & \mc{(7)} & \mc{(8)} & \mc{(9)} & \mc{(10)} \\ 
\midrule
\textbf{Top} 
& -0.087 & -0.279 & 0.087 & -0.018 & 0.111 
& -0.090 & -1.372\tabularnote{$p<0.1$} & -7.257 & -0.006 & 3.279\tabularnote{$p<0.1$} \\ 
$\times$\textbf{Post}  
& (0.083) & (0.204) & (0.083) & (0.016) & (0.240) 
& (0.217) & (0.756) & (4.679) & (0.046) & (1.823) \\ 
\addlinespace
\Block[draw=blue,line-width=1pt]{2-10}{}
\color{red}{Top30}
& -0.127\tabularnote{$p<0.01$} & 0.115\tabularnote{$p<0.01$} & 0.127\tabularnote{$p<0.01$} & 0.004 & 0.102\tabularnote{$p<0.1$} 
& 0.102\tabularnote{$p<0.005$} & 0.162 & 1.101 & -0.031\tabularnote{$p<0.01$} & 1.214\tabularnote{$p<0.01$} \\ 
\color{red}{PostRe} 
& (0.018) & (0.044) & (0.018) & (0.004) & (0.055) 
& (0.049) & (0.152) & (1.070) & (0.011) & (0.424) \\ 
\addlinespace
Top3 
& -0.100\tabularnote{$p<0.1$} & 0.184 & 0.100\tabularnote{$p<0.1$} 
& 0.034\tabularnote{$p<0.01$} & 0.077 & 0.282\tabularnote{$p<0.1$} 
& 1.456\tabularnote{$p<0.01$} & -1.161 & 0.143\tabularnote{$p<0.01$}
& 3.548\tabularnote{$p<0.01$} \\ 
& (0.061) & (0.149) & (0.061) & (0.012) & (0.176) 
& (0.159) & (0.554) & (3.427) & (0.033) & (1.335) \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular*}

\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

One more solution with use of the `tabularray` package. Quite similar to CarLaTeX answer (first +1 was mine), but with use of `talltblr` table and `booktabs` and `siunitx` libraries:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\scriptsize
\begin{talltblr}[
    label=none,     % <---
    entry=none,     % <---
remark{Notes} = { $^{*}\ p<0.1$; $^{**}\ p<0.05$; $^{***}\ p<0.01$.} 
                ]{colspec  = {Q[l, font=\bfseries]   
                              *{10}{X[c, si={table-format=-1.3{**},
                                             input-symbols={()}}]} },
                 colsep   = 2pt, 
                 row{1-3} = {guard},
                 row{2}   = {mode=math},
                 row{odd[5]}= {abovesep=0pt},
                 hline{6,8} = {1-Y}{blue, 1pt},
                 vline{1,Y} = {6-7}{blue, 1pt},
                 }
    \toprule
    &   \SetCell[c=10]{c}   Dependent variables
                &         &         &           & (5)   & (6)    & (7)     & (8)     & (9)      & (10)  \\
    \cmidrule{2-11}
    & \sigma^l      & \sigma^\pi                & \sigma^k
    & \mathrm{ROE}  & \log(\mathrm{der})        & \log(\phi_l)
    & \log(\phi_k)  & \mathrm{TFP}              & \mathrm{HHI}
    &   \mu         \\
    & (1)     & (2)     & (3)     & (4)     & (5)     & (6)     & (7)     & (8)     & (9)     & (10)    \\
    \midrule
Top & -0.087  & -0.279  & 0.087   & -0.018  & 0.111   & -0.090  & -1.372* & -7.257  & -0.006  & 3.279*  \\
$\times$Post
    & (0.083) & (0.204) & (0.083) & (0.016) & (0.240) & (0.217) & (0.756) & (4.679) & (0.046) & (1.823) \\
\SetCell{fg=red} Top30
    & -0.127*** & 0.115*** & 0.127*** & 0.004   & 0.102*  & 0.102** & 0.162   & 1.101   & -0.031*** & 1.214***  \\
\SetCell{fg=red} PostRE
    & (0.018)   & (0.044) & (0.018)   & (0.004) & (0.055) & (0.049) & (0.152) & (1.070) & (0.011)   & (0.424)   \\
Top3 & -0.100*  & 0.184    & 0.100*   &0.034*** & 0.077   & 0.282*  & 1.456*** & -1.161 & 0.143***  & 3.548***  \\
     & (0.061)  & (0.149)  & (0.061)  & (0.012) & (0.176) & (0.159) & (0.554)  &(3.427) & (0.033)   & (1.335)   \\
     \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: and first +1 is mine!

Comment: @CarLaTeX, thank yo very much!

Comment: @You're welcome! I'll steal `table-format=-1.3**` to improve mine!